Configure PDF.js to load the first page of a PDF
We have a system which is generating linearized PDFs on demand. The linearization allows the client to dynamically retrieve particular pages efficiently, however since it takes a long time to generate the files in the first place it still feels slow to the user.
One idea we had was to generate the first page of the PDF and display that to the user while the rest of the PDF is generated in the background.
Is there a way to configure PDF.js so that the first page is loaded from a different data source? e.g. /pdf/page1 and then all other pages load from /pdf/restofpages
Or is there some other good way to integrate our solution with PDF.js?
